No loader is configured for ".node" files: node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node
I am encountering an error when attempting to use Canvas in a newly created Angular project with version 18.x.x. I would appreciate any guidance on resolving this issue. The error details are as follows:
Node Error
[ERROR] No loader is configured for ".node" files: node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node
node_modules/canvas/lib/bindings.js:3:25:
  3 │ const bindings = require('../build/Release/canvas.node');
    ╵                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

12:09:19 PM [vite] Pre-transform error: Build failed with 1 error:
node_modules/canvas/lib/bindings.js:3:25: ERROR: No loader is configured for ".node" files: node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node
I attempted to modify the configuration in the angular.json file, which provided a temporary solution. Specifically, updating the builder option from 'application' to 'browser' (as shown in the highlighted screenshot) allowed the application to function as expected.
Solution
However, requiring each user to modify angular.json for compatibility with Canvas-related libraries is not ideal. I'm seeking a solution that eliminates the need for manual adjustments to angular.json to streamline this process for all users.
